# npm audit - how to make sure I have no production vulnerabilities?

Tags: npm, npm-audit

I'm trying to make sure my project doesn't have vulnerabilities in production, so I ran:

`npm audit > vulnerabilities.txt`

and then I searched for all instances of "Dependency of"

which brings up a list like:

```
Line 199: Dependency of babel-preset-es2015 [dev]
Line 215: Dependency of babel-preset-es2015 [dev] 
Line 230: Dependency of babel-preset-es2015 [dev]
```

Can I assume that if all of them have that [dev] tag, then npm audit found no package vulnerabilities in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the answer is yes.

To validate this, I ran 
`npm audix fix --production`
And then running
`npm audit`
produced a list where every dependency was a "Dependency Of" something marked as [dev].

If at some point npm supports the --production flag directly on `npm audit` then that would make it easier.

Comment: `npm audit --production` was released in npm 6.10.0 via https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/202

Comment: Question is: Does this flag just ignore packages you declared as dev or does it also ignore the dependencies of your production dependencies that are marked as dev? (Recursively, of course.) Seems to me this only affects your top level dependencies, so indirect dev dependencies are still treated as security issues...

Answer (score 0):

In older npm versions you can do below, even in newer versions I've found --production flag very buggy and node still reporting devDependencies, in both cases you can use this instead:

```
npm prune --production --dry-run
```

Above will output any vulnerabilities from inside dependencies. You would need to fix any vulnerabilities manually then though.

**NOTE:** Many projects I have worked with have wrongly had production dependencies inside devDependencies instead of dependencies. This needs to be fixed first of course. (just move the declaration inside package.json and npm i - check exact version inside lock file if needed)

If code from a node_module is used clientside (if it's used can sometimes be tricky to tell) it should be in dependencies (example corejs)

If you have a node backend/hosting then you need to check if it's used in Node BE in production as well.